# Not showing error details in left pane in xcode

Tags: xcode

When I am running app on simulator it is working fine but when I am installing on device using developer profile it is giving error and showing build failed.But when try to see error detail it is not showing anything.I do not know whats the problem..

Please help me.

Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: I don't know what's causing that but can you get an error description by clicking the red marker at the top center of the screen?

Comment: Yes I did the same but it is not showing anything.

Comment: Anything showing in the "Log navigator" for the most recent build?

Comment: I think you need to add provisioning profile certificates and update the same in build settings.